# I want to log the user inputted email value and select menu value to the console after the user clicks the sign up button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, console.log

**Full Question:** I want to log the value of each field (email address & select menu) to the console in the browser. I have made an attempt for this below but it does not seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Shopify Frontend Developer Intern</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Stay up to date with ecommerce trends <br>with Shopify's newsletter</h2>
  <h4>Subscribe for free marketing tips</h4>

  <script>
    function logOptions() {
      var s = document.getElementsByName('Interests')[0];
      var text = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
      console.log(text);
    }

    function logEmail() {
      console.log(document.getElementById('email').value);
    }

    function myFunction() {
      logOptions();
      logEmail();

    }
  </script>

  <!-- <div class="input form"> -->
  <form id="inputform" method="get" action="confirmation.html">
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <button type="submit" id="validate" onsubmit="myFunction()">Sign up now</button>
    <select name="Interests" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Interested in..</option>
        <option value="option1">Marketing</option>
        <option value="option2">Option2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option4</option>
      </select>
  </form>

  <svg>
  <rect width="40" height="3" style="fill:lightgreen" />
  </svg>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: try putting the script tag at the bottom of the html page right before the </body> tag

Comment: keep in mind that when you submit the form the console.log maybe executed on the main page not the confirmation.html page which may be the cause of your confusion

Comment: @A.Mostafa I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: oh also change onsubmit() in the html to onSubmit(). This should work